# Query all array element is in another array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to query documents from a collection where all elements in an array match a condition: both the name field and the quantity should be in and above the minQuantity in the "currentStatus" array.

In this example, I would like to retrieve the documents _id : 1 and 4

```
Collection = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    conditions: [ {name: 'product1', minQuantity: 30},
                  {name: 'product2', minQuantity: 10} ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    conditions: [ {name: 'product1', minQuantity: 50},
                  {name: 'product2', minQuantity: 10} ]
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    conditions: [ {name: 'product1', minQuantity: 10},
                  {name: 'product2', minQuantity: 10},
                  {name: 'product3', minQuantity: 10} ]
  }
  {
    _id: 4,
    conditions: [ {name: 'product1', minQuantity: 10} ]
  }
  ]

currentStatus = [
  {name: 'product1', currentQuantity: 40},
  {name: 'product2', currentQuantity: 20},
]
```